# How to avoid repetition of unique questions in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I need help creating the following program:

The program must randomly select two different pairs of words from either of the lists below, and then display a question based on the selection. I must ensure that the program is not selecting the same synonym-antonym pair i.e. repeating the question.

“Q1: Hot is to cold, as happy is to .... ?”

Answer: sad (user types this.)

“Q2: Ignore is to pay attention, as darkness is to .... ?”

Answer: .....

The program will ask 10 questions. Ensure that each of the questions would not give away the previous answers:

for example:

“Q1: Hot is to cold, as happy is to .... ?”

“Q2: Ignore is to pay attention, as Hot is to .... ?”  - the answer was printed in Q1!

I need to avoid this scenario.

The program must also return the score  and show the correct answers for those that were wrongly typed

Here is the code I have:

```
import random

wordlist1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "simple", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]


wordlist2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "complex", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]



def makeQuestion():

    indexes = range(len(wordlist1 and wordlist2))

    word1 = random.choice(indexes)
    word2 = random.choice(indexes)
  
    ans = input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(wordlist1[word1], wordlist2[word1], wordlist1[word2]))
    if ans.strip().lower() == wordlist2[word2]:
       print (True)
    else:
       print (False)

for x in range (10):
    makeQuestion()
```

The problem that I have is that some questions repeat. Could you please help me avoid that?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clearify please what exactly your goals is. Do you want that each word only occures once? Therefore when a question is asked all 4 words are consumed? There is always 3 words in a question and one word is the answer right? Do you want that each of these words to be consumed and not used again?

Comment: There are many things wrong here. The most glaring is that *you intend for there to be a mapping from questions to answers*; the appropriate data structure for this is a `dict`. You can separately make a list of the dict keys in order to choose repeatedly without replacement.

Comment: But as for the actual, conceptual problem, let me give you a hint: how do you draw multiple random cards from a deck of cards while making sure you don't draw the same card twice? Answer: you **shuffle** it, and then repeatedly pick cards off the top. Right? Do you see anything in the `random` module that might help you `.shuffle` things?

Comment: Another thing in your code that **accidentally** works even though it doesn't make any sense at all, is here: `indexes = range(len(wordlist1 and wordlist2))`. If the lists were different lengths, this would use the length of the second list, *unless the first list were empty*, in which case it would use zero length no matter how many elements were in the second list. Do you understand why?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the entire reason that Python gives you tools like the `for` loop structure, `random.choice` etc. is so that you can  **avoid** using indexes into a list. Unless your code involves doing math with the numerical values, `range` is rarely the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Also: functions should do *one thing*, and it should relate to how they are named. Your function named `makeQuestion` should **make** the question, and **not ask** it. You can do this by for example `return`ing the information that needs to be formatted into the prompt string.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel How does my implementation look?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to remove the words after each question:

```
import random

wordlist1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "simple", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]


wordlist2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "complex", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]



def makeQuestion():

    indexes = range(len(wordlist1 and wordlist2))

    word1 = random.choice(indexes)
    word2 = random.choice(indexes)
    ans = input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(wordlist1[word1], wordlist2[word1], wordlist1[word2]))d

    if ans.strip().lower() == wordlist2[word2]:
       print (True)
    else:
       print (False)
    wordlist1.remove(wordlist1[word2])
    wordlist2.remove(wordlist2[word2])


for x in range (10):
    makeQuestion()
```

Here we are only removing word2, you can do the same for word1 if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `asked` list to keep track of asked questions and added `while` loops to both `word1` and `word2` to keep randomising until a unique pair index is chosen:

```py
import random

wordlist1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "simple", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]


wordlist2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "complex", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

asked = []

def makeQuestion():

    indexes = range(len(wordlist1 and wordlist2))

    word1 = random.choice(indexes)
    # Checks if any of the words were already asked, which the user would know the answers to.
    while wordlist1[word1] in asked or wordlist2[word1] in asked:
        print("\nAlready asked pairs:", wordlist1[word1], "and", wordlist2[word1])
        print("Getting another random choice...\n")
        word1 = random.choice(indexes)
    # adds the pairs that will be asked to the list
    asked.append(wordlist1[word1])
    asked.append(wordlist2[word1])
    
    word2 = random.choice(indexes)
    # Checks that word1 and word2 are not the same so that the answer is not displayed.
    # also checks if one of the pairs was already asked before, so it skips that too.
    while word2 == word1 or wordlist1[word2] in asked:
        word2 = random.choice(indexes)

  
    ans = input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(wordlist1[word1], wordlist2[word1], wordlist1[word2]))
    if ans.strip().lower() == wordlist2[word2]:
        # Also adding answers that were guessed correctly. So, it does not repeat a question that the user already knows
        asked.append(wordlist1[word2])
        asked.append(wordlist2[word2])
        print (True)
    else:
       print (False)
    print("\nAsked questions:", asked)

for x in range (10):
    makeQuestion()
```

The code contains comments and print statements to also describe what their purpose is.

As others have mentioned, deleting the elements after they are asked might be a more efficient solution, but here is an alternative one for you.

**NOTE**: Since the word pool is small, if the user guesses *all* of the questions correctly, this code *will not be able to* find a unique pair and will be *stuck* in an **infinite loop**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
is_to = {
   "female" : "male",
   ...
}

def make_question(is_to):
    
     keys = list(is_to.keys())
    
     example = random.choice(keys)
     
     question = random.choice(keys)

     ans = input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(example, is_to[example], question)
     if ans.strip().lower() == is_to[question]:
       print (True)
     else:
       print (False)


     return dict(is_to).pop(example) # create a copy of the dict with whichever key removed


reduce(lambda is_to, index : make_question(is_to), is_to)
```

Answer (score -1):

As @KarlKnechtel said, the data structure well suited for this problem is a dictionary. Here is the implementation. Let me know if I miss anything.

```py
import random

wordlist1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "simple", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]
wordlist2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "complex", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

d = {i : j for (i,j) in zip(wordlist1, wordlist2)}

def makeQuestion():

    a = random.choice(list(d.items()))
    del d[a[0]]
    b = random.choice(list(d.items()))
    

    ans = input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(a[0], a[1], b[0]))
    if ans.strip().lower() == b[1]:
       print (True)
       
    else:
       print (False)
    del d[b[0]]

for x in range (int(len(d)/2)):
    makeQuestion()
```

Comment: Hi, your code is helpful and useful, but there are still repetitions when I loop it 10 times. Could you please help me and make sure that there are no repetition for 10 times? Thanks

Comment: @Alex Can you explain a bit more about the repetition?

Comment: Run the code and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: @Alex I checked my code even tho I don't understand what you meant clearly, we can remove the repetition but the dictionary I created has 17 items in it, divided by two it gives 8.5. That means we cant iterate 10 times and delete both randomly chosen items(```a``` & ```b```). Am I making sense?

Comment: @Alex However we can iterate to up to 
```len(d)/2``` and avoid the repetitions... i edited my answer check it out and let me know if it solve ur issue.

Comment: How can we iterate up to ``len(d)/2? Could you please show me the code? Thanks

Comment: @Alex Check my answer I have updated it. and accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: We still have answers to the questions repeating in some questions. For example, small is to big as reject is to .... allow (the answer). The next question is: prevent is to allow as exclude is to....? So you see what I mean? some of the answers repeat themselves in questions

Comment: @Alex are you sure maybe i am missing something, I run the code multiple times but am still not seeing what you are trying to say.

Here is a sample ==>


buy is to sell as prevent is to___? fg
False #
ignore is to pay attention as hard is to___? fg
False #
exclude is to include as weak is to___? fg
False #
summer is to winter as win is to___? fg
False #
light is to darkness as reject is to___? fg
False #
dry is to wet as small is to___? fg
False #
male is to female as simple is to___? fg
False #
hot is to cold as sad is to___? fg
False
```
What am i missing?

Comment: Oh I see. It is absolutely fine now. Could you please help me now to the score of how many the user gets right? Thanks

Comment: @Alex You can just create a variable ```score``` and inside your function's ```if ans.strip().lower() == b[1] ```  logic do ```score += 1``` , You can access that score and display it or do some other thing....and btw can you mark my answer correct. I don't know who downvoted it. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex can you show me what you tried? Put it on pastebin or something and share the link.